# Ionic Serve Issue - ng has unexpectedly closed

Tags: linux, windows, .net-framework

I executed this command a

```
F:\ionic-firebase-shopping-cart-master>ionic serve
```

in my command prompt and found this issue

```
ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
[ng] The run command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Please help me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

After clean off your pc environment through the commands below, try it again:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli 
npm uninstall --save @angular/cli
```

and/or

```
npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli
npm uninstall --save @ionic/cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@~10.0.5 //or with your version
// npm install --save @ionic/cli  //if necessary
ng build
ionic serve -l --port=8100
```

It should work after removed the inadequate versions even though it might also related to your SDK and Nodejs version.